# Give permission to folder on Linux to group

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I know this has been asked a few times on here but I am still a little confused exactly how to achieve this.  I have two users, root/sudo and www-data. I want both of these users to be added to a group and then assign ownership of a folder to that group.

What I have tried so far, and where I am getting confused:

I ran this:

```
sudo addgroup admins
```

then

```
sudo adduser root admins
sudo adduser www-data admins
```

followed by

```
sudo chown :admins /myfoldername
```

of course replacing /myfoldername with the actual directory.

However the result is that both users do not have access anymore.. So I feel like I am missing something?

Comment: I don't think you need to bother adding root to the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing maybe the rights on that directory. You might have set 700 on the directory, that means all rights for the owner user, but none for the group and others. Try changing that to 770 or 775.

`chmod 775 /myfoldername`

Links: [chown help](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown), [chmod help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).

Additional explanation: you can set permission to three kind of entities: the owner (which is one single user), a group, and all others.

Comment: So am I right in saying that the chmod permission is applied only to owners of that folder (from the chown command)?

Comment: With chmod you can set permission to the owner, the group or/and others. The chown can set the owner or/and the group. Read the pages I linked.

Comment: One more thing, if you're coming from a Windows environment: you can't achieve the same granularity which Windows and NTFS offers.

Comment: This mostly gets me there. After running chmod 777 /myfoldername, I can create folders, delete, read, etc but I can not create new files in the directory as the user www-data but am allowed to as root

Comment: Where is your directory exactly situated? The whole path to your directory must have traverse rights for that specific user to be able to get there, that means you have to have execute rights on each parent directory for www-data.

Comment: Right. I did sudo chmod -r /mnt where /mnt is the root so being recursive should apply all the way up to my actual folder I believe

Comment: Please check the syntax from the link I posted. :)

Comment: To clarify something else: "/" is the root in Linux.

Comment: ok so I tried "sudo chmod -R g+w /mnt" since g is group and w is for adding write access

Comment: @Radoo ACLs are available in filesystems in Linux too...

Comment: Even doing "sudo -R o+w /mnt"  results in www-data still unable to make files.. I really am not sure as to why. They can still create folders, just not files

Comment: Btw, root/sudo should still have access even if the permission is 000 and whatever the ownership is...

Comment: @Radoo It turns out that what I was doing was correct but my apache user was actually something other than the default www-data. My solution was simply to make that user in the same group. Your answer was the answer to my actual question though so I will mark as an answer. Thanks for your time Radoo

Comment: @TomYan you are right, you have ACLs in Linux. I haven't worked with ACLs. What I know for sure is that ACLs are not available by default, you need to set the mounts to use this feature. Sometimes it might not be your call how the whole system is set up. Still, you are right. It's possible.

Comment: @Radoo AFAIK `acl` is the default option, though it can be disabled with `nocal` and the kernel drivers can be built without ACL support.

Comment: @TomYan I read the wrong (or probably old) document. :( I tried it on a system I have. It does work by default. Thanks for taking the time to argue with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if www-data is inside admins group, type:

```
groups www-data
```

It returns the groups www-data belongs.

root should have all permissions, so you do not need to set any permissions.
then type `ls -l /myfolder` and check if: groups has RWX rights, and the group owning the folder is admins.

But as some others suggested, you configuration is not the best:

www-data is an user created by the web-server installation, and it make also a group created www-data. So you can use it and set www-data as owning group for /myfolder, set rwx permission for group, and root can always do everything.